# MySQL lost connection while updating large tables

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have the following query which updates products stock for specific suppliers.

```
UPDATE
    ps_stock_available AS sa
INNER JOIN
    ps_product AS p 
ON 
    p.id_product = sa.id_product
SET
    sa.quantity = 0,
    p.quantity = 0
WHERE
    p.id_supplier = 18
```

The query is working for suppliers with small amount of products but it gets stuck with supplier over 1k products.

```
/Lost connection to MySQL server during query/
```

I don't have access to configuration files, so I'm looking for a way to decrease the amount of time needed to proccess.

Is there any way to decrease the time needed or update products in multiple batches? I'm using prestashop CMS if anyone is familiar with it.

Comment: Do you have database access to index the `id_product` column in those tables?

Comment: Or try paging of the results.

Comment: @wogsland I have access to database. Would I had to index id_product on both tables?

Comment: Yes add index on `p.id_product`, `sa.id_product` and `p.id_supplier`. Note that the query will finalize even though you cant follow the progress on that current connection. But putting index on those columns will improve the query speed alot.

Comment: If you execute this `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep'` , you will see all active queries that are not sleeping

Comment: Indexing makes reads faster but slows down writes, which is why one doesn't just index everything. If one table is significantly larger you may get most of the bang for your buck indexing just that one. You can also use `EXPLAIN` before a query to see where the pain points are.

Comment: @wogsland @Kay Nelson It seems that database already has indexes created on each table. ps_stocks has 8 & product table has 10 of them created. Could this be the reason for slow updating? `explain` is showing me 1203 rows on product table with 6 possible keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own.

Instead of trying to straight up update both tables at once I'm updating database in batches.

The following code is writen in PHP:

Selects all IDs which fit the criteria for my update (connect to database, execute query)

```
select ps_product.id_product FROM ps_product
INNER JOIN ps_stock_available on ps_product.id_product=ps_stock_available.id_product
WHERE ps_product.id_supplier=18
```

Write IDs into array

```
$i=0;
    $id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id[$i]=$row["id_product"];
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No products with chosen supplier in database.";
    }
```

While looping thorugh array I'm creating specific UPDATE queries for each ID & executing them.

```
$arrlength = count($id);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

$sql2=
"
UPDATE ps_stock_available
SET 
quantity=0
WHERE id_product=".$id[$x]."
";
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo $x.", ";
}
```

It would probably be smart to check mysql connection each time I'm updating database, just to make sure it doesn't disconnects, but it works for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the value of 'Connection read timeout' on your MySQL server.

Change default value in MySQL configuration file (option connect_timeout in mysqld section) -

```
[mysqld]
connect_timeout=100
```

If this file is not accessible for you, then you can set this value using this statement -

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=100;
```

Try setting the value to something more than the current value and see if it work, try increasing the value if it doesn't.